# Does any compound exist with multiple liquid phases?

Tags: phase

I've seen some phase diagrams and I found really interesting, how many exotic solid phases of most elements exist on higher pressure and temperature.

But I've seen always only a single liquid phase and also only a single gaseous phase.

The second is understable, but the first not. I think, if there is an unconventional potential energy field between the molecules, maybe it is not impossible.

Does any chemical compounds with multiple liquid phases exist?

If not, why not?

---

*Extension:* Well, superfluid helium is one of them. Maybe I don't formulate enough well, but I think on a distinct phase border, like between ice-I and water. As I know, the superfluid helium is a mix of its superfluid and normal fluid phases.

Comment: Well, superfluid Helium is one of them. Maybe I don't formulate enough well, but I think on a distinct phase border, like between ice-I and water. As I know, the superfluid Helium is a mix of its superfluid and normal fluid phases.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49510/why-so-few-fluid-phases

Comment: I suspect helium may be the only one. At sufficiently low temperatures, superfluid $\ce{^3 He}$ phase separates from $\ce{^4 He}$, producing two distinct superfluid phases, presumably with an *almost* invisble meniscus between them. Not sure whether this satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Both of He3 and He4 can be superfluid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason why chemical substances with multiple liquid phases shouldn't exist.

In fact there is evidence for the existence of a least a [second form of (surprise) liquid water](http://phys.org/news/2013-07-liquid-liquid-phase-transition-low-temperature.html). If you search the Web for [liquid-liquid phase transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamorphism#Liquid.E2.80.93liquid_transitions) you will find more of these, e.g. [cerium](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.125503).

Comment: You may want to describe the second liquid phase of water in a little more detail, or else readers might mistake it for "polywater" which turned out to be a miss.